# socket.io - issue with the socket variable while using namespace

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, websocket, socket.io

I'm following a book which has a code snippet for socket.io namespaces. the version specified in the book is socket 0.9

this is the below code for a simple chatroom using namespaces.

```
exports.initialize = function(server) {
  io = io.listen(server);
  var chatInfra = io.of("/chat_infra")
    .on("connection", function(socket) {
      socket.on("set_name", function(data) {
        socket.set('nickname', data.name, function() {
          socket.emit('name_set', data);
          socket.send(JSON.stringify({
            type: 'serverMessage',
            message: 'Welcome to the most interesting ' +
              'chat room on earth!'
          }));
          socket.broadcast.emit('user_entered', data);
        });
      });
    });
  var chatCom = io.of("/chat_com")
    .on("connection", function(socket) {
      socket.on('message', function(message) {
        message = JSON.parse(message);
        if (message.type == "userMessage") {
          socket.get('nickname', function(err, nickname) {
            message.username = nickname;
            socket.broadcast.send(JSON.stringify(message));
            message.type = "myMessage";
            socket.send(JSON.stringify(message));
          });
        }
      });
    });
}
```

i'm trying to recreate the code using the latest socket version. but i'm having trouble getting the `socket.nickname` variable in the chatCom namespace. the socket.nickname variable in the chatCom namespace returns undefined because of the local scope.

here's my version

```
exports.initialize = function(server){
  io = io(server);

  var chatInfra = io.of('/chat_infra');
  chatInfra.on('connection',function(socket){
    socket.on('set_name',function(data){
      socket.nickname = data.name;
      console.log(socket.nickname);
      socket.emit('name_set',data);
      socket.send(JSON.stringify({
        type:'serverMessage',
        message:'Welcome to the most interesting chat room on earth'
      }));
      socket.broadcast.emit('user_entered',data);
    })
  })

  var chatCom = io.of('/chat_com');
  chatCom.on('connection',function(socket){
    socket.on('message',function(message){
      message = JSON.parse(message);
      if(message.type === 'userMessage'){
        message.nickname = socket.nickname;
        socket.broadcast.send(JSON.stringify(message));
        message.type = 'myMessage';
        socket.send(JSON.stringify(message));
      }
    })
  })
}
```

Is there a way i can access the nickname value in the second namespace?
I'm able to access the same socket instance in both namespaces. but however, the nickname property seems to be erased when i invoke it from a different namespace.

Output of console.log

```
socket id in /chat_infra is : Zo0kfigUFJOZIgH8AAAB and socket nickname is kj
socket id in /chat_com is : Zo0kfigUFJOZIgH8AAAB and socket nickname is undefine
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry that I can't verify this myself right now (and also that I can't comment yet), but hopefully I can help you figure it out.

Both `chatInfra` and `chatCom` should have a `connected` property that is an map of all the current sockets connected to each. If the socket is not shared/reused in each namespace, perhaps they still share the same connection ID.  So, you may be able to get the nickname from `chatInfra.connected[socket.id].nickname`.

If that doesn't work, console.log each of their `connected` properties and see their differences.  Also, socket.io handles JSON natively, so you don't need to JSON.parse and JSON.stringify your objects.

Comment: I'm able to invoke the same socket instance in both namespaces. but the nickname property seems to be effectively removed when i invoke it from a different namespace. this is the output of my console.log

//**socket id in /chat_infra is : Zo0kfigUFJOZIgH8AAAB and socket nickname is kj**
//**socket id in /chat_com is : Zo0kfigUFJOZIgH8AAAB and socket nickname is undefine**

Comment: In my code I store all my data in a  socket.data object. Does that already exist in the socket object natively?  I seem to recall a similar problem of my data not "saving" and using socket.data solved that I believe.

Comment: it should be chatInfra.**connected**[socket.id].nickname . thanks for pointing me in the right direction

Comment: can you explain better? I've the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Instead setting `nickname` to `socket`, you can set `nickname` to the `client` object of `socket`, such as `socket.client.nickname = data.name`.